# jasmine spy on then-request library

Tags: typescript, mocking, jasmine

I have the following TypeScript code

```
LoadClientConfigs(): Promise<ClientConfig> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            request('GET', 'config/clients.json').done(function (res: any) {

                if (res.statusCode >= 300) {
                    reject(res);
                }

                const clientConfigs: ClientConfig = JSON.parse(res.getBody());
                resolve(clientConfigs);
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }

    });
}
```

Now I'm writing Jasmine tests and I need to mock the **request** method.  Request is from the npm package then-request and I import it in the following manner

```
const request = require('then-request');
```

How do I mock the **request** method to return a specific set of data when called.  So far this is what I have

describe('Client Config', () => {
        it('Should load the correct config for the given client', () => {

```
        createSpy("request").and.callFake(() => {
            console.log('requesting');
        });

        ConfigService.LoadClientConfigs();
    })
})
```

However the fake method does not get called.

Answer (score 0):

If you change

```
const request = require('then-request');
```

to

```
var request = require('then-request');
```

then you can mock the **request** function like this

```
request = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(() => {
            console.log('requesting');
          });

ConfigService.LoadClientConfigs();
```

I have not executed this answer on my computer but it should work.